# Problem about $T-$conductor in Hoffman-Kunze book

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I was checking my notes from Hoffman-Kunze book on linear algebra where I came across this result.

> Assume $W,V,Z$ are vector spaces where $W \subseteq V \subseteq Z$ are subspaces of $Z$. The linear operator $T:Z\rightarrow Z$ is defined and $W,V$ are invariant under $T$ (i.e. if $v\in V , w\in W$ then $m(T)v\in V,m(T)w\in W$ for any polynomial $m$ over the scalar field). If $\beta\in Z$ is a vector, then the $T-$conductor of $\beta$ into $V$, $f(t)\in S_T(\beta;V)$, must divide the $T-$conductor of $\beta$ into $W$, $g(t)\in S_T(\beta;W)$, i.e. $f(t)\mid g(t)$ or equivalently $g(t)=k(t)f(t)$ for some polynomial $k(t)$ ($f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are monic generators of the conductor ideals, see definition below please).

First the definition

> Let W be an invariant subspace of $T$ and let a be $\alpha\in V$. The $T-$conductor of $\alpha$ into $W$ is the set $S_T(\alpha ; W)$ , which consists of all polynomials $g$ (over the scalar field $F$) such that $g(T)\alpha\in W$. $S_T(\alpha ; W)$ is an ideal in the polynomial algebra $F[t]$ and $\color{red}{\text{the unique monic generator of the ideal } S_T(a ; W) \text{ is also called the } T-\text{conductor of }\alpha \\ \text{ into } W}$

Now my question here are two-fold:

$\qquad 1$-Why degree of  $g$ is greater than $f$?

$\qquad 2$-Why $f(t)\mid g(t)$?

If it helps, I encountered this in the chapter $7$, "cyclic decomposition and sub-spaces", in the proof of theorem $3$.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi \in S_T(\beta;W)$, then $\phi(T)\beta \in W \subseteq V$ implies $\phi \in S_T(\beta;V).$  Therefore $S_T(\beta;W) \subseteq S_T(\beta;V).$

In particular, as long as you accept that $S_T(\beta;V) = (f)$ and $S_T(\beta;W)=(g)$ are nonzero principal ideals of $F[t]$, it follows that $g \in S_T(\beta;W) \subseteq S_T(\beta;V) = (f).$   This means that $g(t) = f(t) \cdot q(t)$ for some $q(t) \in F[t]$ so that $f(t) \mid g(t)$ and therefore the degree of $f$ is less than or equal to the degree of $g$.

Comment: Thanks for your response, which notation is weird?, please inform me to edit it. The proof abour deg$(g)>$deg$(f)$ was interesting. Also, can elaborate on your proof using division algorithm, I assume you are implying $g(T)=q(T)f(T)+r(T)$ and then applying both sides on $\beta$?

Comment: @K.K.McDonald I edited most of the issues with notation in your question.  Hopefully it all makes sense.  As for the last part of my answer, I'm actually going to remove the reference to the division algorithm.  While at some level I think it applies, the more important fact is that $\deg(f_1f_2) = \deg(f_1) + \deg(f_2)$ and the definition of the principal ideal.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thank you! I'm out of my tunnel vision (O_O'), when you are reading it in context of that long theorem 3, you eventually lose the thread somewhere, but now with your help I'm back on the saddle. Thanks a lot!